# MySQL Server Stopped -The MYSQL80 service started and then stopped

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I had been running a MySQL server for weeks now. Everything had been working perfectly until yesterday, when the MySQL server simply stopped. I realized the Service had stopped, and whenever I try to start it I get an error message that says "The MySQL80 service on Local Server started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other programs or services."

So far, I have done some research online and have found solutions that include modifying the my.ini file. After looking for it for quite a while, I realized it wasn't being stored in Program Files, but in the hidden ProgramData folder. I opened the my.ini file and it was empty (I am not sure if this File is generated every time the service starts or if there should already be something in there).

Other solutions include running the mysqld --install and mysqld --initilize commands, but my Command Prompt won't recognize these commands. I am pretty much lost as to what to attempt now, and I am also pretty much confused since it had been running for weeks without any issues whatsoever.

What are some more troubleshooting steps for this?

Comment: *I get an error message that says "The MySQL80 service on Local Server started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other programs or services."* Service manager makes a mistake. MySQL starting fails to start (not fails itself). Investigate error log.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your reply. Which error log are you referring to?

Comment: Did you check MySQL Server logs? The message you get comes from Windows service manager, which doesn't actually know anything about your programs.

Comment: MySQL Server Logs - General and Error Logs, of course. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have attempted to go into the Server Logs but there is nothing on there. All I get is a message that says that There is no connection to the MySQL server, so no logs can be generated.

Comment: That's strange. You can also [start the server from a command prompt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html), so you have a chance to see fatal error messages.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Well, I attempted that and turns out I no longer have a mysqld file.